# OSX Mavericks ATLAS install failure from source AND Macports

Tags: macports, osx-mavericks, lapack, blas, atlas

I'm trying to install ATLAS (because I need LAPACK/BLAS) on Mavericks from source, since installation fails via Macports (possibly for the same reason?). The compiler can't be located despite numerous attempts to set it:

```
sudo ../configure -b 64 --prefix=/usr/local/atlas --with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=../../lapack-3.4.2.tgz -C alg /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.7 -C if /opt/local/bin/gfortran-mp-4.7 --shared
```

The salient error is:

```
Unable to find usable compiler for ICC; abortingMake sure compilers are in your path, and specify good compilers to configure
(see INSTALL.txt or 'configure --help' for details)make[1]: *** [atlas_run] Error 1
```

The Macports error message is:

```
--->  Fetching distfiles for atlas
--->  Verifying checksums for atlas
--->  Extracting atlas
--->  Applying patches to atlas
--->  Configuring atlas
Selected C compiler: /opt/local/bin/clang-mp-3.3
Selected F77 compiler: gfortran48
Error: org.macports.configure for port atlas returned: configure failure: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port atlas for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_math_atlas/atlas/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port atlas failed
```

Comment: I cannot help with the installation issue, but LAPACK/BLAS is included with OS X. The easiest way to use it is to `#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>` and link in the Accelerate framework (`-framework Accelerate` with the Apple linker, or, in Xcode, add it to the project in the usual way).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately in this case it's someone else's software, which I'm using, that has the LAPACK/BLAS dependency, and I'm trying to avoid too much hacking. I suppose I could suggest they make some platform-dependent mods.

Comment: This is not a fix, but I was able to specify the compilers well enough to pick up the Accelerate versions. But I've left this question as unanswered in the hope that someone can fix it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you need fortran or not, using the +nofortran flag with macports works on mavericks.  If you need fortran, try setting the compiler to gcc4x instead of clang-mp-3.3